# Fade In after initial fade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site trying to get the navigation to fade in after the initial fade up of the background. HEre is the site: http://mccraymusic.com/newsite/

I know the navigation doesn't work and is not styled yet. If you click "enter site" you'll see the fade action I'm talking about with the background. You'll also notice the current way that the navigation acts currently as well.

Thanks

Comment: @Lavi. Any luck with my answer? Notice the $('.navbar').animate({ opacity : 100 });

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback argument that exists in pretty much all jquery effects methods. For example:

```
$( '#background' ).fadeOut( 'fast', function(){
  $( '#nav' ).fadeIn( 'fast' );
});
```

Edit:::

Just took a look at your code. Try this:

```
$('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
  $('#bg').attr('src', 'assets/images/'+image); 
  $(this).fadeIn(1000);
  $('.navbar').animate({ opacity : 100 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to chain the effects

```
.fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pkQcA/1/